# cannot add capabilities to custom wp user role in child theme

Tags: php, wordpress, user-roles, child-theming

In my child theme's /`function.php` ; I am calling the below, which seems to register the new role 'marketing_admin', because it is now present in my Wordpress dashboard; however **my array of capabilities are being completely ignored**. All my code pertaining to this new role is below:

```
add_role(
    'marketing_admin',
    __( 'Marketing Admin' ),
    array(
        'read'         => true,  
        'edit_posts'   => true,
        'publish_posts' => true,
        'edit_pages'   => true,
        'edit_others_pages' => true,
        'publish_page' => true,
        'edit_pages'=>true,
        'edit_published_pages'=>true,
        'publish_pages'=>true,
        'edit_private_pages' => true,
        'edit_others_pages' => true,
        'delete_pages'=>true,
        'delete_others_pages'=>true,
        'delete_published_pages'=>true,
    )
);
```

Comment: Where & when are you calling the add_role function?

Comment: At the bottom of my child theme's function.php file

Comment: What action / hook are you using? Can you show us that code please?